# track AB clicks with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript

I want to run build some simple AB testing on a website. I would like it to be as light as possible to avoid slowing down pageload, and plan to run a single test at a time, with a single variable. I'm not skilled with javascript, but with some hammering away, I got a simple 50/50 randomizer running:

```
var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;{
  if (randomNumber == 1)
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = "Please Signup";

  if (randomNumber == 2)
    document.getElementById("id1").innerHTML = "I insist you signup!";
}
```

[**http://www.bootply.com/0oum4mlhzW**](http://www.bootply.com/0oum4mlhzW)

I am lost at the next step though. I want to track the clicks on signup button, based on what content was showing at the time. I'll need to track # of visitors, # of clicks, and then be able to see this content in html somewhere.

Would also like to use cookies (or another method) to make sure a returning visitor always sees the same content.

Comment: There are tools that will let you serve two different versions of a page.  That would be better than littering your JavaScript with if/else blocks, plus you'll be able to collect stats on the data.

Comment: Have you considered using google analytics?

Comment: I know of a number tools that do this and much much more, including Google Analytics, Optimizely etc, but I'm looking for something single purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/vDEZ7/1/)

```
var btn = document.getElementById('target1');
var track = document.getElementById('track');

// Retrieve
if (localStorage.getItem("trackNum") != ""){
     track.value=localStorage.getItem("trackNum");
}

var cnt = track.value;
btn.onclick = function(){
    cnt++;
    track.value = cnt;

    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("trackNum", track.value);
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="id1">Do you think you might consider signing up?</h1>
  <button id="target1" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up!</button>
    <input type="text" id="track" value="0"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that its tracking clicks, but how can I marry the two? I need to track clicks depending on which h1 is showing.

Comment: Then just marry both of them inside the `click` event

Comment: sorry, that's beyond me. how?